# How long will it take to reach the closest earth like planet

Tags: space

Using the engines today how long will take humanity to reach earth like planets?

Comment: Using what engines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HD 219134b is apparently closest "super earth"](http://www.washingtonpost.com/news/speaking-of-science/wp/2015/07/31/nasa-just-found-the-closest-super-earth-ever/); 21 light years away.
New Horizons, our speediest yet, is currently running at [about 15 km/sec relative to the sun](http://www.livecometdata.com/new-horizons-spacecraft/).
At 9.46e12 km/lightyear HD 219134b is 2e14 km away 
At 3.16e7 seconds per year, New Horizons will travel about 4.74e8 km/year.
2e14/4.74e8 = **422000 years**.

HD 219134b isn't even a very good earth; gravity is too high.

Comment: Apparently new horizons will eventually start to loose momentum to about 13 km/s?

Comment: @cstruter Yes, of course. New Horizons is still well under the gravitational influence of the sun, and will continue slow for some time. I picked its current velocity as an estimate of a speed near the best we can currently do, not an immutable constant. I doubt New Horizons is even headed towards HD 219134b.

Comment: Current spaceships need to go much faster than 15 km / sec.

Comment: Voyager 1 is travelling at 17km/s